# using var with jquery selectors

Tags: jquery

I am having problem using variables as selectors with jquery.

how do I select last td using $t?

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

var $t = $('#mytable')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and combine with [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/). This way you search the table for the last `td`

```
$t.find("td:last")
```

From [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page):

[`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

> **Description**: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

[`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)

> **Description**: Selects the last matched element.
>
> Note that :last selects a single element by filtering the current jQuery collection and matching the last element within it.

Answer (score 1):

See working example here http://jsfiddle.net/MXjFP/2/

```
var $t = $("#mytable");
var $td = $t.find("td:last");
alert($td.html());
```

It's a little confusing and if at all possible I'd remove the '$' from your variable names to make it a little easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
$t.find('td:last')
```